# Problems with Packages, modules and functions

Tags: python

I am having diificulty importing a module that i've created in package.

here is my code :

```
import test.addition._addition 
import test.subtraction._subtraction 
import test.multiplication._multiplication 


class calcul:


    def addition(self, a, b):

        self.c = _addition(a,b)
        print self.c

    def subtraction (self, a,b):

        self.c = _subtraction(a, b)
        print self.c

    def multiplication (self, a, b):

        self.c =_multiplication (a, b)
        print self.c
```

As you noticed from the first 3 lines of the code,
I've stored the module `_addition` in a folder called addition and again I stored the addition folder in a folder called test.
It is the same for subtraction and multiplication.
In each folder, I've created a module `__init__` to make sure that it is declared as a packages.

To be even more clearer, below is the code in the module `_addition`

```
def _sous_addition(a,b):
    return float(a) + float(b)
```

The problem is that python told me that :

global name '_addition' is not defined

Comment: Because it's `test.addition._addition`. You can alias it to just `_addition` with `import .. as ..` or `from .. import ..`.

Comment: Excuse me, what do,you mean by "alias it to just  _addition with import ..as..?"

Comment: He means your should import it like import test.addition._addition as _addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing `import test.addition._addition`, then the name that is available in your local scope is `test`, and you can access the `_addition` function using `test.addition._addition`. You need to use its full name.

If you want to import the function with the name `_addition` into the local scope, you need to write either of these things:

```
from test.addition import _addition
import test.addition._addition as _addition
```

Comment: I am still having problem. Now python tell me that the module is not callable.

Comment: Still the very *same* problem...? Or something new?

Comment: After reading your expanlanation and debugging my codes, I think I understand better with your explanaition. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `test.addition._addition._addition` to call that function.

What's more important is:

**NEVER USE THE SAME NAME FOR MODULE AND FUNCTION!!**

It's really really bad coding style and would bite you sooner or later. It seems deceze is confused by this. Avoid it please.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am stilll new in coding. I would like to call just the module for now and not the fonction because I am planning to add another more functions in the module.

Comment: @maximus Whether you call function or not, just don't use the same name. Naming is probably the most difficult part of programming, you'll learn that as you code more.